# Unable to compile workflow-project

Tags: msbuild, sharepoint-2007, cruisecontrol.net, workflow-foundation

I have a build-server running CC.Net. So far I never had any problems compiling projects on the build server (which has no VS installed, just use the .Net Framework).

But now I have a new projects and I get this message:

```
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\Windows Workflow Foundation\v3.5\Workflow.Targets(127,5): error : Compilation failed. Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

Has anyone any hint's on what's causing this problem?

What might be of some interest is the fact, that this is a SharePoint project wich includes a SharePoint workflow. But this shouldn't stop the project from being able to be compiled.

Comment: Just to check: It couldn't be a x86/x64 build configuration issue?

Comment: well, to project-configuration is set to 'Any CPU' - if that's what you getting at.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant: I'd give setting it to x86 a try ... but I now suspect it's rather a reference that cannot be found. You could debug the build by adding a message task to the Workflow.targets script before line 127 and print out its various params like @(ReferencePath).

Comment: Please add @<name> to your comment replies - this will trigger a notification and I'll get back to it and answer much sooner.

Comment: @Filburt: OK, I looked at the referenced assemblies, but this looks good to me. All assemblies can be found, mostly from c:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\V2.0 and c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5.

Answer (score 0):

The [problem with LoaderExceptions described here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/windowsworkflowfoundation/thread/8a5b80e8-e90f-44ef-bd80-b66b60cfab02) sounds like what you are seeing. Maybe targeting 3.0 instead of 3.5 does fix your issue too.

Comment: well, I have the toolsversion of the csproj already set to 3.5 and I also have 

<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\Windows Workflow Foundation\v3.5\Workflow.Targets" />

So there shoudn't be any mismatch in this respect.

Is there any way to figure out what the loader actually tries to load?

Comment: do you know any way to figure out what the loader tries to load?

Comment: @nyn3x Did you already try to extract the $LoaderExceptions property? If you already tried all the properties used in Workflow.targets I couldn't think of any more.

Comment: @nyn3x You said you did set the toolsversion to 3.5 - the linked article suggests setting it to 2.0 and target the \v3.0\Workflow.targets.